# Background Image on Jython GUI

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to create a GUI in Jython. I want to import a background image that I can place buttons and textfields on. I've already created the frame with the buttons and labels in their appropriate places, I just need to know how to import a background image. The GUI is implemented in Jython.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Java swing material, essentially you are just using the same api in python syntax. This might help: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=599393